# When to register Google Cloud Messaging?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

My question is when exactly do I need to Register the broadcast receiver?

Do I do it (or attempt to do it) every time the application starts up?
Do I keep the registration id somewhere (persistent of course) and check if that is null only register then?

Currently I register when the application starts up (if/when they have been authenticated), however I am not sure if this is good/bad.

Please advise.

Comment: That is good approach. You store the GCM registration ID in shared preferences. Whenever first activity starts, you check whether shared preferences are null. If they are, contact GCM and store GCM reg ID in shared prefs. If it is already stored in prefs, simply skip registration.

Comment: @Dhaval Is shared prefs better than a SQLite database?  I currently use the database for other data anyway and the infrastructure is easily extendable.

Comment: Both are good. Shared Prefs don't get destroyed even when app is updated, same as SQLite. They are destroyed upon uninstalling. I use shared prefs. SQLite is also fine, but you'll need to write more code for just an ID. It's a personal choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your remote server implementation (as a requisite for this kind of infrastructure). In my third-party server, I've implemented a timeout mechanism which makes that if a client doesn't send a keepalive every X minutes, it's considered a *timeout* and therefore I remove it from the database (so no further messages will be sent to this client).

So, in my case, the answer is **yes**, it's ok to register each time your app starts up, and not just because of the timeout, but also because the `GCM` system might change your `id` whenever it needs (which doesn't occur often, but might happen).

Comment: I have noticed that my ID hasn't changed at all (on my dev device), but I bet it would(or actually could rather) change in the future.

Comment: Yes, it might happen at some point (in my case, one of the devices I used for tests did from one day to another), so it's always a good idea to register each time you start your app. It won't make any harm and it's better to prevent.